# Geoserver meta-tiling factors

Tags: geoserver, wms, tiles

I am trying to setup meta-tiling in Geoserver 2.8.0 (I can version up if necessary) in order to prevent multiple labels on polygons which span across tiles.

I am using Leaflet (1.0 RC) on the client.

```
L.tileLayer.wms("http://178.62.114.162:8080/geoserver/geolytix/wms", {
  layers: 'seamless_locales',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  styles: 'seamless_locales',
  tiled: true,
  tilesorigin: [-180, 90]
})
```

I was initially confused about the tiles origin. Turns out that it doesn't matter whether I use [-180, 90] or [-180, -90]. The result is the same. See screenshot. Left without meta-tiling, right with meta-tiling.

[image]

There are still some duplicate labels in the meta-tiled example. As suggested in the comments this might is probably due to the meta-tile size which is 3*3.

I am trying to change the meta-tile size but have yet been unable to do so.

Edit:

I changed the labels to a point layer of the polygon centroids but labels are not rendered across the tile boundaries and I don't like the idea of having a separate layer for labels.

[image]

I am having a workaround with a non-tiled layer [leaflet plugin](https://github.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer) which works well. It's neither the prettiest or quickest solution but it works.

Comment: By reading http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#tiled the left bottom is probably at [-180, -90] if your Leaflet map is in EPSG:4326. However, 3x3 metatiles are not so big and it is possible that large polygons are split to several metatiles and are getting many labels. By putting label into centroid of the polygon this might be avoided.

Comment: Guess the problem is related to the 3*3 meta tiles.

Comment: With the integrated GeoWebCache you can use bigger metatiles http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/concepts/metatiles.html. The default is 4x4 but it can be increased.

Comment: Metatile size can be set in the layer settings, but you really need to set partial labels in the sld

Comment: It is confusing that the tiled=true metatile is always 3x3 and layer settings do not change that. What layer settings does change is the metatile size when the endpoint /geoserver/gwc/service/wms? is used. See http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Tell-me-about-tiled-yes-and-tiled-true-td5132809.html

Comment: Are metatiles always 3 by 3 without gwc?

Comment: Yes, they are always 3x3, not configurable, as the other 8 tiles are kept in memory for a small amount of time.